# Running delta queries using Microsoft.Grpah c# sdk 5.^

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-sdks, kiota

Trying to run delta queries for SharePoint drive root using new Microsoft.Graph version 5.0.0 nuget package.
Seems the Delta function is missing from the Drive API.
Is there any way to do delta queries using the new C# SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to make one extra call. Assume that you have `siteId`.

Get drive for the site, then get drive item of the root and then use id of root drive item to get delta.

```
// get site drive
var drive = await graphServiceClient.Sites[siteId].Drive.GetAsync();

// get root drive item
var rootDriveItem = await graphServiceClient.Drives[drive.Id].Root.GetAsync();

// get delta response for root drive item
var deltaResponse = await graphServiceClient.Drives[drive.Id]
                           .Items[rootDriveItem.Id]
                           .Delta
                           .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks user2250152 for the prompt response. In my case there is no MicrosoftGraphDelta property, but there is Delta property that I can use. Do you know how can we pass the delta token?

Comment: @ArsenKhachatryan You are right. I was using rc5 but 5.0.0 has only delta. Thanks